# I want to make a for loop that asks and answers its questions but i think i want 2 variables in the for llop and idk how

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] cars = new String[3];
        cars[0] = "bmw";
        cars[1] = "tesla";
        cars[2] = "lambo";

        String[] questions = new String[3];
        questions[0] = "What Is The First Car?";
        questions[1] = "What Is The Second Car?";
        questions[2] = "What Is The Third Car?";

        for (int i=0, x=1; i<questions.length, x<cars.length; i++, x++) {
            System.out.println(questions[i]);
            System.out.println(cars[x]);
        }

    }
}
```

I don't want it simple, i want it with for loop, not like that:

```java
System.out.println("What is the first car?");
System.out.println("bmw");
```

and so on... If anyone knows please help.

Comment: You only need a single variable since you have three questions and three answers, which match.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what OldBoy said, since the index of each question corresponds to the index of each answer, you would only need one variable to represent this index.

```
String[] cars = new String[3];
cars[0] = "bmw";
cars[1] = "tesla";
cars[2] = "lambo";

String[] questions = new String[3];
questions[0] = "What Is The First Car?";
questions[1] = "What Is The Second Car?";
questions[2] = "What Is The Third Car?";

for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(questions[i]);
  System.out.println(cars[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps!